# CakePHP 3.4 group by foreach loop the result

Tags: cakephp, foreach, grouping, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am struggling with foreaching grouped records.

It is a collection of hours saved with the same date, and I want to group them in my view/output.

Any suggestions? I have tried a ton of different approaches. Here is how I get them from DB. (date  = type date in mysql "Y-m-d"). And outputting them normal. All my trials and errors.. I could write all day, and I am sure it is a simple solution for someone that know how cake libs work.

```
$hours = $this->UserHours->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [
            'UserHours.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 
            'month(UserHours.date)' => $this->request->data('date.month')
        ],
        'order' => ['UserHours.date ASC'],
        'group' => ['UserHours.date']
    ]);
```

And the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($projecthours as $hour):
debug($hour);
?>
<tr>
 <td> <?php echo $hour->date;?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $hour->start; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $hour->end; ?> </td>
 </tr>
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to loop trough the records correctly when grouped from controller. I cant find them when using the "group" condition in controller. I only get the first record of each date when using "group".

:) I guess they are somewhere inside there, but I cant figure this one out. I am quite new to cake 3.4..

Comment: I find that a judicious 'debug' of the data returned by 'find' helps me immensely figure out how to loop on it/display it.  But then I have some convoluted models :-)..

Answer (score 0):

After you get the grouped dates, you get all dates matching each grouped date.

```
// get grouped dates
$dates = $this->UserHours->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [
            'UserHours.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 
            'month(UserHours.date)' => $this->request->data('date.month')
        ],
        'order' => ['UserHours.date ASC'],
        'group' => ['UserHours.date']
    ]);

$hours = [];
// find all dates for each grouped date
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $hours[] = $this->UserHours->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [
            'UserHours.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 
            'month(UserHours.date)' => $this->request->data('date.month')
        ],
        'order' => ['UserHours.date ASC']
    ])
    ->where(['UserHours.date' => $date->date]);
}

foreach ($hours as $values) {
    foreach ($values as $hour) {
        dd($hour->date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then why group at SQL level at all? That doesn't make much sense if you retrieve all data anyways. The OP is most probably simply looking for grouping _results_.

Comment: It makes so much sense that it solves the problem. First query get distinct data, and for each distinct data the second query get all data matching it and index it in an array.

Comment: Well, I could fix a flat tire by filling the hole with a dead weasel, that might work, but I think you'd agree that it's not an overly good solution ;) What you're doing is unneccesary, as it retrieves all data anyways, and could possibly issue hundreds of additional queries, while the resulting data would essentially be the same as when simply not grouping on SQL level at all. Grouping the result set should be all that is needed.

Comment: I am not getting you, I would like if you could write an answer.

Comment: Cool, I will see.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected result, as that is how SQL grouping works, you get one value per group, there simply will be no further values in the results.

If you just want to output things in a grouped manner, then that's something different, for that you have to select all data, and then you could simply group the results on PHP level, for example using the collection/resultset method `groupBy()`:

```
$query = $this->UserHours->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        'UserHours.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 
        'month(UserHours.date)' => $this->request->data('date.month')
    ],
    'order' => ['UserHours.date ASC']
]);

// callback usage required as `date` is most likely an object
$groupedByDate = $query->all()->groupBy(function ($row) {
    return $row['date']->format('Y-m-d');
});
// if it weren't an object, then passing the fields name would already do it
// $groupedByDate = $query->all()->groupBy('date');

foreach ($groupedByDate as $date => $group)
{
    // $date = the value of UserHours.date shared by all entities in the group
    // $group = an array of UserHour entities that share the same UserHours.date value
    foreach ($group as $hour)
    {
        // ...
    } 
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Queries Are Collection Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Collection::groupBy()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::groupBy)**